# why the normalization of my dataset in python doesn't change the results of my classification method?

Tags: python, knn

I am a complete beginner in machine learning and data analysis, I am using a dataset(the iris dataset) in python and did the K-Neighbor classification method, and I did get an accuracy of 0.97%. I have an exercise which wants me to explain what would happen if I would normalize the input data.

I normalized it by using

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import preprocessing
# load the iris dataset
iris = load_iris()
print(iris.data.shape)
# separate the data from the target attributes
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
# normalize the data attributes
normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize(X)
```

and then I took this normalized_X in my code for the KN-Method but my accuracy doesn't change, is this normal?

Comment: I have posted an answer, but I think this question is better suited for stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normalisation step is meant to reshape your data space such that the spread of the data along all feature dimensions is roughly the same. This makes it easier and quicker to arrive at a good solution in some cases, but does not always guarantee a better solution than the case without scaling. It certainly is a good practice, so you should carry on doing it in this and other problems. It also helps gradient-based optimiser (such as Stochastic Gradient Descent) to converge at a good solution, again sometimes quicker but does not always guarantee better performance. You can find some authoritative information on the matter in the following video by Andrew Ng:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gV5fD8Xbwgk

There are plenty of other resources related to this, if you just search for, say "the purpose of feature scaling in machine learning" on Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: Thank you for your information, I will answer in a much more correct manner, regards